# CSS - Multiple image layers within a container?

Tags: css, image, layer

Is it possible to create a container where you can have an image of a pre-determined width/height. Inside it will have multiple images layers which are different z levels.

I can achieve this using:

```
.layer-box-image{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.layer{
    position: absolute;
    margin:auto;
}
```

But this does not work when I resize the page etc as it is absolute and thus everything else moves through this container.

```
<div class="img-container">
    <div *ngFor="let layer of myLayers">
        <img id="4-image" class="layer img-responsive  layer-box-image" name="4-layer" src={{layer.fullImageURL}} style="z-index: 14" />
        <img id="15-image" class="layer img-responsive  layer-box-image" name="15-layer" src={{layer.fullImageURL}} style="z-index: 15" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks all!

Comment: Is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/Ln4r93mb/